# Should mySQL take this long, or is configuration wrong?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL for the first time and surprised at how long it takes for basic queries to finish compared to SQL Server Express.  I'm a novice when it comes to databases, so hoping I can change something basic in my syntax or configuration to make it "work".

I'm using mySQL 5.7, Workbench 6.3.  Server/Client are on same local machine, only 1 user (root).

Take this example.  I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE original_table
(
   myTimeStamp datetime,
   PRIMARY KEY (`myTimeStamp`)
);
```

For fun, I filled the table with sequential datetimes at one-minute intervals from 2009 to 2017 = 4.2 million records.  Now, to simply copy that table to another new table takes **272 seconds**.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table
```

And trying it with an insert takes **209 seconds**:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table; 
INSERT new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

Looking at Windows Task Manager is surprising because CPU does not go past 4% of capacity and mysqld only takes 0.1-2% of CPU.  Workbench uses 0.3 % of CPU.

ONE INTERESTING CLUE: if I instead try to copy to a temporary table, the task is completed 10 times faster (**22 seconds**), and Windows Task Manager shows mysqld takes 5-10% of CPU:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE newTemp LIKE original_table; 
INSERT newTemp SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

Any idea what is going on, or is this how mySQL performs?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is a highly configurable DB.  Out of the box settings may not be optimum for your hardware and usage.  This article throws some lights about configuring InnoDB https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

Just for the sake of experimentation, execute these commands and then repeat the filling of the table again to see if there is a reduction in time.  Inserts to temp table are faster because temp table stays in memory while inserts into a normal table are committed to the disk after every insert statement.

```
set global innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
set global general-log=0
```

Once you are done with the above experiment, let's enclose your insert into a transaction. Not sure if it will make a difference but just for the sake of finding out.

```
start transaction;
--- your insert sql
commit;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That improved time to 68 seconds.  I'll read the article you posted to see if more I can configure.  With optimal configuration, how long should I expect something like this take using a standard home computer (3.2 GHz)?  I mean, not specific numbers, but are we talking 5 seconds or 50 seconds?

Comment: @MikeD the type of data inserts you are experimenting with are not a routine.  MySQL has bulk inserts which should be much much faster.  In typical database based applications, there are far more read queries compared to insert/update queries. In such scenarios, DB should be optimized for faster read.